# Как в openpyxl с помощью save сохранить в разные файлы при одной переменной openpyxl.load_workbook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Есть однолистовой excel. В одной из колонок указаны повторяющиеся подразделения.
Хочу сделать из одного excel много, но в каждом отдельное подразделение.
Не хочу применять много переменных wbX = openpyxl.load_workbook, потому что Х неизвестное количество.
Проблема в том, что не пойму как обнулить wb2_s = wb2.active после записи, в следующий файл пишется, что в предыдущем + новое.

```
import openpyxl

# файлы для работы
xl_f_from = 'users_all_exists.xlsx'
xl_f_to   = 'new/users_sort.xlsx'

# переменные
perv_stoka  = 2
posl_stroka = 605

# открываю книгу с подразделениями
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(xl_f_from, data_only=True)
wb1_s = wb1.active

# создаю итоговую книгу
wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
wb2_s = wb2.active

# считать колонку подразделений в множество чтобы сравнивать при сборе информации
podrazd_exists = set()
for i in range(perv_stoka, posl_stroka+1):
    podrazd_exists.add(wb1_s['e'+str(i)].value)

# выбирая одно подразделение выбираю по нему все подразделения из колонки
for indexP, podr in enumerate(podrazd_exists, 1):
    wb2_s.append(["Логин","ФИО","Статус","Должность","Подразделение"])
    for i in range(perv_stoka, posl_stroka+1):
        if wb1_s['e'+str(i)].value == podr:
            wb2_s.append([wb1_s['a'+str(i)].value, wb1_s['b'+str(i)].value, wb1_s['c'+str(i)].value, wb1_s['d'+str(i)].value, wb1_s['e'+str(i)].value])
    wb2.save(xl_f_to.replace('.', str(indexP)+'.'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что нужно перед каждой записью просто инициализировать файл

```
# выбирая одно подразделение выбираю по нему все подразделения из колонки
for indexP, podr in enumerate(podrazd_exists, 1):
    # создаю итоговую книгу
    wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
    wb2_s = wb2.active
    wb2_s.append(["Логин", "ФИО", "Статус", "Должность", "Подразделение"])
    for i in range(perv_stoka, posl_stroka+1):
        if wb1_s['e'+str(i)].value == podr:
            wb2_s.append([wb1_s['a'+str(i)].value, wb1_s['b'+str(i)].value,
                          wb1_s['c'+str(i)].value, wb1_s['d'+str(i)].value,
                          wb1_s['e'+str(i)].value]
                         )
    wb2.save(xl_f_to.replace('users', str(indexP)).replace('sort', str(podr)))
    wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
    wb2_s = wb2.active
```